# AJAX not working with web server but working on local filesystem; IIS 7.5

Tags: jquery, iis, iis-7.5, http-status-code-404, same-origin-policy

Here is the call:

```
$.get('js/questionJSON.json', function(data){       

    //erroneous code
},'json');
```

I can't seem to figure out why the call won't work on the local web server, but will work on the local file system.  I was wondering if it had something to do with Same-Origin-Policy.

Comment: Is there an error in the Javascript console? Violating same-origin-policy produces an error there.

Comment: Since you don't specify a hostname in the URL, it's by definition the same origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out eventually.  IIS 7.5 does not come with JSON as a MIME type.  After adding JSON as a MIME type it worked fine.